# How to find the correct port that can be used for talking to qcom modem over usb?

Tags: android, c, port, embedded-linux, termios

I have a rooted device connected to my Ubuntu 16 machine. I have enabled its DM port from device with secret code *#0808#*

On Windows, I can see a COM port in device manager but on linux I am unable to find the correct port.

I have tried to check the new /dev/android4 that appears when enabling the DM port but it doesn't seems to be correct port when trying to open it. I am getting following error on it:

> Error from tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device

This is my code to open this port:

```
int set_interface_attribs(int fd, int speed)
{
    struct termios tty;
//    memset(&tty, 0, sizeof(tty));

    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error from tcgetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return FAILURE;
    }

    cfsetospeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);
    cfsetispeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);

    tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD); /* ignore modem controls */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8;      /* 8-bit characters */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;  /* no parity bit */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;  /* only need 1 stop bit */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS; /* no hardware flowcontrol */

    /* setup for non-canonical mode */
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
    tty.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
    tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    /* fetch bytes as they become available */
    tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error from tcsetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return FAILURE;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}

jint initDiag(char* comPort)
{
    int ret;
        
    debug("initDiag %s \n", comPort);

    if (signal(SIGPIPE, sigpipeHandler) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        debugWarning(" cannot capture SIGPIPE\n");
    }
         
    // open /dev/android4
    hSerial = open(comPort, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (hSerial < 0)
    {
        debugError("open %s \n", comPort);
        return FAILURE;
    }
     
    /*baudrate 115200, 8 bits, no parity, 1 stop bit */
    if(set_interface_attribs(hSerial, B115200) == FAILURE) {
        debugError("Failed to set attributes.\n");
        return FAILURE;
    }
    
    return hSerial;
}
```

Any help, How can I do this?

*Update* ls /dev/

```
$ ls /dev/
acpi_thermal_rel  fb0        i2c-16    loop13  loop-control        ppp       stdin   tty21  tty39  tty56      ttyS14  ttyS31   vcsa
android4          fd         i2c-2     loop14  mapper              psaux     stdout  tty22  tty4   tty57      ttyS15  ttyS4    vcsa1
autofs            freefall   i2c-3     loop15  mcelog              ptmx      tpm0    tty23  tty40  tty58      ttyS16  ttyS5    vcsa2
block             full       i2c-4     loop16  media0              pts       tpmrm0  tty24  tty41  tty59      ttyS17  ttyS6    vcsa3
bsg               fuse       i2c-5     loop17  mei0                random    tty     tty25  tty42  tty6       ttyS18  ttyS7    vcsa4
btrfs-control     hidraw0    i2c-6     loop18  mem                 rfkill    tty0    tty26  tty43  tty60      ttyS19  ttyS8    vcsa5
bus               hidraw1    i2c-7     loop19  memory_bandwidth    rtc       tty1    tty27  tty44  tty61      ttyS2   ttyS9    vcsa6
char              hidraw2    i2c-8     loop2   mqueue              rtc0      tty10   tty28  tty45  tty62      ttyS20  uhid     vfio
console           hpet       i2c-9     loop20  net                 sda       tty11   tty29  tty46  tty63      ttyS21  uinput   vga_arbiter
core              hugepages  initctl   loop21  network_latency     sda1      tty12   tty3   tty47  tty7       ttyS22  urandom  vhci
cpu               hwrng      input     loop22  network_throughput  sda2      tty13   tty30  tty48  tty8       ttyS23  userio   vhost-net
cpu_dma_latency   i2c-0      kmsg      loop23  null                sda3      tty14   tty31  tty49  tty9       ttyS24  v4l      vhost-vsock
cuse              i2c-1      lightnvm  loop3   nvme0               sda4      tty15   tty32  tty5   ttyprintk  ttyS25  vcs      video0
disk              i2c-10     log       loop4   nvme0n1             sda5      tty16   tty33  tty50  ttyS0      ttyS26  vcs1     zero
dri               i2c-11     loop0     loop5   nvme0n1p1           sg0       tty17   tty34  tty51  ttyS1      ttyS27  vcs2
drm_dp_aux0       i2c-12     loop1     loop6   nvme0n1p2           shm       tty18   tty35  tty52  ttyS10     ttyS28  vcs3
drm_dp_aux1       i2c-13     loop10    loop7   nvme0n1p3           snapshot  tty19   tty36  tty53  ttyS11     ttyS29  vcs4
drm_dp_aux2       i2c-14     loop11    loop8   nvme0n1p4           snd       tty2    tty37  tty54  ttyS12     ttyS3   vcs5
ecryptfs          i2c-15     loop12    loop9   port                stderr    tty20   tty38  tty55  ttyS13     ttyS30  vcs6
```

Comment: It seems as if `/dev/android4` is not a standard communication device, so you get the error. You might like to investigate what kind it is, perhaps `lsusb` and `lsmod` and so on are helpful.

Comment: What does shell command `ls -l /dev/android4` produce?  What is the declaration and assignment  of `comPort`?   A modem device connecting *"over USB"* is likely to use CDC ACM, which would create a **/dev/ttyACM**x device node.   Why does half of *"**my code** to open this port"* look so familiar to me?

Comment: @thebusybee lsusb prints "Bus 001 Device 013: ID 05c6:676c Qualcomm, Inc." Please share how can I find /dev/* with this information?

Comment: @sawdust Added update in the question. There is no port like containing ACM.

Comment: *"Added update ..."* -- That is not an adequate response to any of the three questions posed to you.

Comment: @sawdust lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Aug 24 12:27 /dev/android4 -> bus/usb/001/014    when   Bus 001 Device 014: ID 05c6:676c Qualcomm, Inc.   Is it what you want to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general, regarding;

```
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 05c6:676c Qualcomm, Inc.
```

The 'Bus' number references the hardware I/O Hub inside your computer.

The 'Device' number references which external I/O device of several that are attached to that internal I/O Hub

To make it easy:

```
sudo apt install hardinfo
```

Then read [how to identify a device](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToIdentifyADevice/USB)

Then to setup the external device for I/O access read [how to mount an external device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160273/access-usb-drive-on-ubuntu-server)  which is discussing an external hard drive, but the basic steps are the same.

then read: [connecting to an external modem](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1161217&seqNum=9)